# Display nth payment of a recurring series?

Tags: civireport, drupal-views, recurring-contributions

Is there any way to display "nth Payment" of a recurring series? I am looking for a way to display with a contribution and/or line item result that this is the 3rd, 4th, 5th payment in the recurring series. I can work with either a civi report or a Drupal View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this with a Drupal View and adding the [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) module.

I created a view using Contributions. The format was Table with Aggregation Options.
I added the  Filter Criteria and Fields that I wanted to display.

In the Format:Settings--

1. I "grouped and compressed" the Recurring Id field
2. "Count" the Contribution ID field (this column is labeled # of Payments)

So my view displays the Recurring Id with the # of Payments

Comment: Nicely done 